# Have the same CSS for a kind of item without using class=

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Is there a way to just program a CSS to automaticaly apply itself (for exemple) on all the `<I />` that's on my web page ?

my master page :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css" />

 <!-- this is my own CSS below -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="icon.css" />
```

My short CSS, icon.css, in a different file :

```
i
{
   font-family:Verdana;
}
```

Exemples of use on web pages :

```
    <i class="ms-Icon ms-font-xxl" > 
        This is not Verdana 
    </i>

    <i class="ms-Icon ms-font-l" style="font-family:Verdana;">
        This text has been forced to verdana
    </i>
```

In other words, i would like the style to apply to both of my `<i />` without specifying it in the `style` nither in the `class` ...

---

Edit :

I just realized the fact that if a item have a specified class, and that class have a CSS, it overwrite the CSS of your stylesheet... I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Jacob Gray's comment, I managed to come up with this :

```
 i {
    font-family:Verdana,sans-serif !important
   }
```

Seems like the `!important` somehow overwrite the CSS of the `class="ms-Icon ms-font-l"` and that is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The inline `style` attribute is with the biggest priority in the CSS. Remove the inline-style and use only external CSS. You are also using 2 external stylesheets as CDN  ( Content delivery network ). You have to check if the `<i></i>` element is styled somehow in them. Try to remove the CDN stylesheets and apply the code below in your external stylesheet.

```
i {
 font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(C)ascading (S)tyle (S)heets. You need to take care of the priority levels of css. e.g. with some basic html like this:

```
<style src="styles.css">              external styles: lowest priority
<style>i { color: red; }</style>      embedded styles: medium priority
<i style="color: green">foo</i>       inline styles:   highest priority
```

Since you have inline styles, that style overrides any similar rules applied elsewhere.

Comment: But if you look at my exemples, even the one that has no style inside the `<>` dosen't appears in verdana

Comment: `i[style]{color:orange !important} !important: highest(est) priority`

Comment: There's also a whole pile of rules relating to specificity of selectors. it may well be that there's some `html body div table tr td i`-type style rule that ends up counting as more specificic than your general `i` rule. Use your browser's dom debugger. it should show you exactly what styles apply to your `<i>` and where they came from. should tell you where/how the verdana's coming from.

Comment: WAIT ! Does the pages that inherits from a master page also inherit the css ?

Comment: what do you mean, inherit? html has no inheritance.

Comment: ASP.net master pages and their web form

Comment: browsers will have no clue what the server's doing. they just see one single html document coming out to them. whether that's from a static .html file, or cobbled together from the output of a billion different components on the server is irrelevant - it's just one chunk of html to the browser. that means any css files loaded/style rules applied apply to ALL of the matching html, not just whatever chunk of asp.net code output the particular html.